# How to use concat() to append to multiple columns in a single mysql update

Tags: mysql, concatenation, multiple-columns

I can't figure out the syntax for Mysql update with multiple concatinations. I want to be able to append a string to the end of the string stored in the database but do it to multiple columns all at once. I can do one column at a time just fine with this

```
UPDATE `table1`.`column1` SET `category1` = CONCAT(category1,'$value[0]',) WHERE `id`='$id';
```

But when I try to do it to multiple columns in the same table I get a syntax error.

```
UPDATE `table1`.`column1`
SET `category1` = CONCAT(category1,'5'),
    `category2` = CONCAT(category2,'5'),
    `category3` = CONCAT(category3,'5'),
    `category4` = CONCAT(category4,'5'),
    `category5` = CONCAT(category5,'5'),
    `comments` = CONCAT(comments, 'jfsaklfsad')
WHERE `for_student_id`='46';
```

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

I can't find the syntax for separating each concat.

Comment: perhaps it's only "UPDATE table1 SET ..." -- otherwise show us your table structure

Comment: If we assume `table1` is your table, then what is `column1`?

Comment: You qualify a table_name with a schema (database name), `UPDATE mydatabase.table1 SET `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to MySQL docs, [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) does not support such syntax. You must reference the table name, without the column, before the SET:

```
UPDATE `table1`
SET `category1` = CONCAT(category1,'5'),
    `category2` = CONCAT(category2,'5'),
    `category3` = CONCAT(category3,'5'),
    `category4` = CONCAT(category4,'5'),
    `category5` = CONCAT(category5,'5'),
    `comments`  = CONCAT(comments, 'jfsaklfsad')
WHERE `for_student_id`='46';
```